# Flex actionscript datatable column names are encoded - how to decode?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, datatable, escaping

I am returning a .NET datatable to Flex Actionscript via a web service. Once I have the datatable then I want to grab the column names.  The following code outputs my column names:

```
for each (var tcolumn:Object in datatable.Columns){
   trace('Column:'+tcolumn);
}
```

This works ok, but the column names are somehow encoded, so a column name that is actually "1-9" is output as "_x005B_1-9_x005D_"

Anyone know the best way to decode the column name?  The unescape function seems to make no difference.
Thanks.

Comment: 0x005B is `[` and 0x005D is `]`